# can't compress whole file with tar?

Tags: tar, compression

I'm not an expert with tar (xz) but I have a video (FLV) and it's size 95MB.

I would like to compress it and I was using this command

```
XZ_OPT=-9 tar -Jcvf myfile.tar.xz 1.flv
```

but I keep getting this error :

```
tar: myfile.tar.xz: Cannot write: Broken pipe
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

and myfile.tar.xz has only 24MB of my video.

Comment: Have you tried just `tar -Jcf myfile.tar.xz 1.flv`? Also, you're going to have better luck converting a video rather than compressing it to save disk space.

Answer (score 1):

#### What is a tar archive?

TAR is a file format holding multiple files in one. It was initially created for **t**ape **ar**chives. Such a tar-file may be referred to as **tarball**.

By default there is no compression involved. However today's versions of `tar` can compress files using an external compression program if installed. With e.g. the command line option `-z` a gzip compression is made, with the option `-a` a file is compressed according to the file extension given (`tar.gz > gzip`, `tar.xz > xz-compression`, etc.).

#### What compression to use?

The compression algorithms used with a tar archive are **lossless**, i.e. there will alwas be a limit below which we can not further compress data without a data loss.

Images, videos, or audio files can be compressed using lossless formats but this is not done too often because these files are still too big for use in the Internet or on limited data storage.

Hence such files are compressed with a **lossy** compression algorithm. Mostly these losses will be almost unnoticeable but from highly compressed JPG-images, MPG-videos or mp3-audio files we all know of the artifacts that are introduced on compressing too much.

#### Why not use compressed tarballs for multimedia content?

What was said above makes it obvious that after we had already chosen to use a lossy compression to crunch data down we can not further compress these date with an additional lossless compression algorithm. It would be a waste of time to try with only very little benefit. Sometimes a lossless compression may even lead to a growth of already highly compressed content.

Therefore using tarballs on multimedia content is only done to hold more than one file in an archive but not to further compress it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether compressing one file will reduce the size. But here is the command

```
tar -cvf foo.tga filetocompress
```

C is for create a tar file. Use xvf to uncompress

Comment: Why the `.tga` extension? That's usually for a particular image format. Do you mean `.tgz`?